# class holding multiple instances which inherits their methods

Tags: java, oop, class

I am pretty new to Java, so I may be using incorrect terminology. I am trying to gracefully extend a class to a new class which holds multiple instances of the superclass. For example, say I have a class

```
class Rose{
   String smell;
   Rose(String smell){this.smell=smell;}
   void sniff(){ println("smells "+smell);}
}
```

And I want to define a class like...

```
class Bouquet extends Rose{
   ArrayList<Rose> roses;
   ...
}
```

holding multiple roses. My actual code has something like 20 methods, and for most of them the extended method would be

```
void sniff(){
   for( Rose one: roses) one.sniff();
}
```

Is there a way to construct `bouquet` in such a way that I don't need to explicitly define these silly loops? I'm not tied to `ArrayList`, I could even make a new super class if that's the way to go about it. However, it is important that I can send a `bouquet` instead of a `rose` argument to externally written methods.

EDIT:
Haha, I think my flower metaphor was a big fail. :) But your input is good; you guys have clarified my thinking a bit.

In my real problem, there are a set of operations that define how to add instances of the base class together into a new instance of the base class. Perhaps a better metaphor would be twisting a number of small fabric strands together into one rope. External methods should treat a rope and a strand exactly the same.

It does seem like `extends` is wrong, any other suggestions?

Comment: A list of roses is not a _type_ of rose, so your `Bouquet` class shouldn't be extending `Rose`. It might help to google "Java inheritance" and read some articles to learn about the basics :-)

Comment: You're all right. Bad example, I've edited the post to explain the situation better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont really need to extend bouquet from roses. You extend only when there is an IS A relationship, like you have Flower class and Rose is a Flower. But bouquet is not a rose. Ideally you should have a bouquet class which HAS many roses. If there is a 1:N relationship, then you will have to loop through to get individual items.

Answer (score 1):

Although we can implement anything to our desire, but there are few flaws in your class designs in regards to abstraction.

A `bouquet` is a collection of rose, so it shouldn't extend rose, but rather have it as a List inside it, which you have anyway. It doesn't make much sense to extend on rose and also have it as property inside bouquet. Instead, create a `Base class` called `Flower` and then `extend` that to create rose.

Define the sniff function inside Flower Class, making provision to `override` it in derived class, if you need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

#### It would be wrong.

I would have voted Shamims answer up, if he hadn't introduced the flower class, which is not a reasonable assumption from your question.

```
ArrayList <Rose> bouquet;
```

might be all you need. But you can't use a Bouquet as a Rose. Bouquet.split (); could make sense, but Rose.split would be a very different thing.

The `is-a` question gives you a rough idea, whether inheritance is a reasonable thing. It's not always the final answer, but if it doesn't fit, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, correct me if I'm wrong, but to me it seems quite obvious that the real question has nothing to do with flowers or roses, but the author is simply trying to create an example.

In a real application there *could* be an **is-a** relationship and the problem is valid. For example, I have had to use this pattern when handling callbacks: you have one `MyCallback` interface, a couple of concrete implementations, and to be able to register multiple callbacks you have a `MultipleMyCallback` class that has a list of `MyCallback` it delegates all calls to. You get exactly the same annoying for loop in every method.

I think you could do this via a Java dynamic proxy. Or if you're feeling adventurous even using something like [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) But I recommend against it. **Just accept that this is a fact of life with Java and write the 20 methods and be done with it.**

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot of hacks, no, there is no easy way to do this. I'd highly recommend reading about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Basically, you only want to use inheritance to enforce an `is-a` relationship - what this means is that your subclass should be substitutable for your base class in all situations. The natural question is therefore, is a bouquet a rose, and the answer here is no, it is not, thus inheritance is not suitable for the job.

Answer (score 0):

In addendum to the answers posted, when it comes to naming your methods it will be better if you replace the sniff() method with getSmell().